# Small shift on pageviewcontroller caused by scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using an PageViewController with 4 pages (let's call them **sections**).

2 of them have a **tableView** in them.

I found out that there is a small shift on the left section of each table views. This shift appears when you first swipe right to the tableview and you swipe back left. Then the shift appears.

It seems like the scrollview around the tableview is causing this issue.
I tried to set `view.bounds = 0` in the `viewWillAppear` callback.

I can't find any solution yet.
Any ideas what is causing this issue ?

Comment: Can we get a screenshot?

Comment: to what @NRitH said, can you also post some code? I just created a sample project to test and everything seems to be working fine.